# Finding strings with odd number of the same symbol appearings

Tags: regex

An array of strings is presented, example:

```
Lorem Ipsum
"Lorem Ipsum
"Lorem Ipsum"
Lorem Ipsum "Lorem Ipsum
Lorem Ipsum "Lorem Ipsum"
"Lorem Ipsum" Lorem Ipsum "Lorem Ipsum
"Lorem Ipsum" Lorem Ipsum "Lorem Ipsum"
```

The goal is: to find strings which have an **odd** number of this symbol --> **"** (quotation mark) AND doesn't end with **"** (while using a single RegEx)

Expected result:

```
"Lorem Ipsum
Lorem Ipsum "Lorem Ipsum
"Lorem Ipsum" Lorem Ipsum "Lorem Ipsum
```

Just wanted to add a quotation mark at the end of each found string, but now am struggling :c

That's the best I got, but it fails on multiple levels:
`^(([^"]*\"){2})*[^"]*$`

Comment: So `Lorem Ipsum"` should not match, correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might start the match with matching at least a single double quote, and prevent matching newlines adding \n to the negated character class:

```
^[^"\n]*"(([^\n"]*"){2})*[^\n"]+$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yhdi6r/1)

If the string should end on a non whitespace char other than a double quote:

```
^[^"\n]*"(([^\n"]*"){2})*[^\n"]*[^\s"]$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0WiXL5/1)

Comment: ...and in first case, could replace matches of `^([^"\n]*"(([^\n"]*"){2})*[^\n"]+)$` with `$1"`. If `\K` is supported could replace matches of `^[^"\n]*"(([^\n"]*"){2})*[^\n"]+\K$` with `"`.